# cutting a mesh object into equal segments for individual export to .dae

Tags: mesh, objects, export, edit-mode

I am not sure if this has been answered already, but as a newbe to Blender V2.73a, I have listed the steps I have taken so far and what I need to achieve.

1. Created a plane, scaled to 25 blender units in X and Y plane
2. Subdivided this into 65,536 faces
3. Sculpted a terrain from the plane using sculpt mode
4. UV Un-Wrapped and Texture painted the entire terrain

What I need to achieve now is it break this single mesh object into 5 equal pieces across the X and Y plane so that each piece (now 5 x 5) can be exported as a separate collada file complete with its texture map for import into Secondlife. I have trawled youtube and wiki and the various forums but with no joy...I am also rubbish at phython, so I am on bended knee in the hope that some kind person can provide an answer..

Many thanks in advance...Kushiel

Answer (score 1):

Go in edit mode with <kbd>Tab</kbd>
Select a loop where you want a cut with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>RMB</kbd>
[image]
hit <kbd>V</kbd> to cut and <kbd>RMB</kbd> to cancel movement
[image]
Repeat this all along your mesh on the same axis
[image]
Now on the other axis, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>RMB</kbd> the 1st loop and <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>RMB</kbd> to add the cut loops to your selection
[image]
hit <kbd>V</kbd> to cut and <kbd>RMB</kbd> to cancel movement, repeat on the same axis
[image]
You can select each separate part with mouse over and <kbd>L</kbd> but...
[image]
Select all with <kbd>A</kbd> and hit <kbd>P</kbd> then select by *loose part* in the separate menu
[image]
now every square is a separate object sharing the same material and keeping the UV
[image]
Don't forget to change the origins if needed, by default they'll use the base object's origin.

Comment: Thats a great help thanks, but are the steps the same if I have run the decimate modifier against the whole mesh object, as I need to create 4 levels of LOD (level of Detail) lowest, low, med and high, and the original source.

What I have found is once all the objects have been cut and decimate ran against them it shows all the edges out, so I end up with gaps in the mesh object.

Comment: it could work if u used decimate with "unsubdivide" with an even number. Else you'll have trouble cutting or making parts fit without limiting decimate to vertex groups inside the objects

Comment: Maybe you could cut decimated triangulated mesh with boolean modifier on a cube based grid to keep the overall shape. but it's more complex.